# Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d, with $P(X_i>x)=e^{-x}$, prove $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n/ \log n =1$ a.s

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d, with $P(X_i>x)=e^{-x}$, prove $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n/ \log n =1$ a.s

Solution:It seems that

Since $P(X_i>x)=e^{-x}$, we have $P(X_i>\log n)=e^{-\log n}=1/n$.
Thus $\sum P(X_i/\log n>1)=\infty$
According to BC lemma II, $P(X_i/\log n>1\ i.o)=1$

Since $P(X_i>x)=e^{-x}$, we have $P(X_i>(1+\varepsilon)\log n)=e^{-(1+\varepsilon)\log n}=1/n^{(1+\varepsilon)}$.
Thus $\sum P( X_i/(1+\varepsilon) \log n>1)<\infty$
According to BC lemma I, $P(X_i/(1+\varepsilon)\log n>1\ i.o)=0$

My question: How to show  $\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n/ \log n =1$ a.s,
It seems that I need to show $P(\|\lim \sup_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n/ \log n-1\|>\epsilon\ i.o)=0$

Can any one help me for it? Not good at analysis. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've shown that $\mathsf{P}(1\le \limsup X_n/\ln n < 1+\epsilon)=1$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Thus,
$$
\mathsf{P}(\limsup X_n/\ln n=1)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{k\ge 1}1\le \limsup X_n/\ln n <1+k^{-1}\right)=1.
$$

Comment: Get it!  Thanks a lot!